# Inclinometer chart

Tags: javascript, charts

Somebody knows a chart library for inclinometers?
Example
 [image]

where the data should be :

```
sensor:3 -> signal:56          sensor:3 -> signal:74
sensor:2 -> signal:45          sensor:2 -> signal:21
sensor:1 -> signal:23          sensor:1 -> signal:32
Day 0                          Day 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you might check [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-inverted), quite easy to configure. For your A-Axis, B-Axis I would just stick to 2 graphs placed next to each other.

Comment: I did, but  Highcharts is not free

Comment: ok, it is free for non commercial use. but nothing in your question pointed out that requirement though.